# Magento 2 custom attribute value returns "No"

Tags: magento2, attributes, custom-attributes

I'm trying to get custom attribute value by using:

`$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);`

however I keep getting "No" as actual value, no matter which custom attribute I'm trying to get, it all returns "No", include both simple and configurable products.

I also tried to get the label and it returns the correct label:
`$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getLabel()`

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Hey please use below code :

```
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->setStoreId($currentStoreId)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

In above line i have just added **->setStoreId($currentStoreId)** .

Comment: What's the best way of getting store id, I tried a few options, none of them works. This is one of them: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-store-information-store-id-code-name-url-website-id/

Comment: Ok, I have correctly get my store id but it still doesn't work for me. The above code returns 'No'.

Comment: ok, so try  below code                                                                            $objectManager = Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->loa‌​d($product_id);
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('vendor')->setStoreId(0)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

Comment: I get this error:

Comment: `Error filtering template: Invalid method Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor::loa‌​‌​d`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **color** attribute here,

you can use below function in your block file:

```
/* $this->productModel is Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;*/

public function getColorValue($optionId){
    $colorValue = '';
    if($optionId) {
        $attribute = $this->productModel->getResource()->getAttribute('color');
        if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
            $colorValue = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionText($optionId);
        }
    }
    return $colorValue;
}
```

call the function as

`$block->getColorValue($product->getColor())`

you will get the color value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to this Code to get attribute Value in Magento 2.

```
 $_getMyAttr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('my_attribute');

 // Get Value
 $attrTestValue = $_getMyAttr->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
 // Get Label
 $attrTestLabel = $_getMyAttr->getStoreLabel();
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy Solution here

-> Go to **Store-> Attributes ->Product ->open your attribute** and go to proprties.
here just change attribute scope to "**Global**" and you will get your value in your code.

**echo $product->getYourAttributeCode();**

If this will fix your issue please mark as a solution.

Thank You